# Draw2d js: How can I keep the ports on the top of the figure?

Tags: draw2d-js

After reading a lot in order to manipulate the position of the ports, I found another problem: when I select a port that is positioned below the figure, as shown in the images.

[image]

[image]

My question is: How can I keep the ports on the top of the figure?
This is my code:

```
var leftLocator = new draw2d.layout.locator.InputPortLocator();
var rightLocator = new draw2d.layout.locator.OutputPortLocator();

leftLocator.relocate = function(index, figure) {
  var width = figure.getParent().getWidth();
  var height = figure.getParent().getHeight();

  var x = width / 4;
  var y = height / 2;

  figure.setPosition(x, y);
}

rightLocator.relocate = function(index, figure) {
  var width = figure.getParent().getWidth();
  var height = figure.getParent().getHeight();

  var x = width * 3 / 4;
  var y = height / 2;

  figure.setPosition(x, y);
}

elemento.createPort("input", leftLocator);
elemento.createPort("output", rightLocator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the "toFront" method at onDragStart event:

```
OutputPortFigure = draw2d.OutputPort.extend({
  NAME: 'OutputPortFigure',
  init: function() { ... },
  onMouseEnter: function() { ... },
  onMouseLeave: function() { ... },
  onDragStart: function(x, y, shiftKey, ctrlKey) {
    this._super(x, y, shiftKey, ctrlKey);
    this.toFront(this.getParent());
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with some of my figures.

I found a solution that can help but it's not the best one i think.

I create a hidden figure that holds the Ports (Implement repaint method to re-size the child figure when the parent one changes)

```
var Hidden = draw2d.SetFigure.extend({
    NAME: "Hidden",
    init : function()
    {
        this._super();

        this.addPort(new draw2d.InputPort('port1'), new draw2d.layout.locator.InputPortLocator());
        this.addPort(new draw2d.OutputPort('port2'), new draw2d.layout.locator.OutputPortLocator());

        this.setDimension(300,150);
        this.setAlpha(0);
    },
    onDoubleClick: function(){
    }
});

var Test = draw2d.SetFigure.extend({
    NAME: "Test",
    init : function()
    {
        this._super();

        this.hidden = new Hidden();
        this.addFigure(this.hidden, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator(this));

        this.setAlpha(0.8);
        this.setDimension(300,150);
        this.setRadius(10);
        this.setStroke(3);
        this.label.setColor("#0d0d0d");
        this.label.setFontColor("#0d0d0d");
        this.addFigure(this.label, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator(this));

        this.tooltip = null;
    },
    repaint: function(attributes){
        this._super(attributes);
        if(this.hidden != undefined) this.hidden.setDimension(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    },
    onDoubleClick: function(){
    }
});
```

if you have a better solution i'll be happy to see it :)

i discovered this when i was implementing a figure that can have a loop connexion